# Выбор размера шрифта

Tags: шрифты

Подскажите пожалуйста какого размера стоит выбрать шрифт для программирования, чтобы глазу было комфортно, сам определить затрудняюсь. Сейчас в основном использую монитор 24 дюйма, шрифт Consolas 12pt, сглаживание ClearType.

Задал вопрос именно на ХешКоде, потому что приходится много работать с кодом и интересует мнение программистов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд Consolas лучшее что я встречал. Сам использую 14, ну тут уже факторы влияют, мое зрение + размер монитора.

Comment: На вкус и цвет... Например мне больше всего нравится Ubuntu Mono

Answer (score 2):

Комфортный размер шрифта индивидуален для каждого. Попробуйте поэкспериментировать. Рекомендую Notepad++, в нем можно масштабировать документ (Ctrl+колесико) и ещё в нем много всяких полезностей.

Comment: Плюсую, зависит от индивидуальных особенностей зрения.

Answer (score 1):

Воотще зависит от:

- DPI монитора
- Сглаживания
- Цветовой схемы
- Личных предпочтений

Моим выбором оказался [Ubuntu Mono](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family) 13.

Screenshot: [VIM Ubuntu Mono](http://ompldr.org/vZG5lcA)

Так же хорошими являются:

- [Terminus](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/)
- [Envy Code R](http://damieng.com/blog/tag/envy-code-r) (без кириллицы, а жаль)
- [Liberation](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts) Mono
- [DejaVu](http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/) Sans Mono

---

И учитывая, что Вы на Windows, я бы вам порекомендовал установить [gdipp](http://code.google.com/p/gdipp/) с параметрами [gdipp_setting.xml](http://ompldr.org/vZG5ldg/gdipp_setting.xml)

Comment: `gdipp` - очень крутая штука, спасибо.

Comment: А какой вообще смысл перечислять шрифты без кириллицы? А gdipp я не понял.

Comment: @karmadro4 - как я понимаю это утилита которая "учит" форточки по человечески рендерить текст...

Пройдите по ссылке и проскрольте вниз, там есть немного скринов

Comment: > А какой вообще смысл перечислять шрифты без кириллицы? А gdipp я не понял.
Просто Envy Code R уж очень симпатичный шрифт, остальные с кириллицей.

Answer (score 0):

От цвета шрифта и фона тоже многое зависит....Экспериментируй с размерами и цветовой палитрой. Оптимально, когда глаза меньше всего уставать будут от зрительной нагрузки. Успехов в программирование...

Answer (score 0):

Отличный вопрос. Сам как сейчас помню месяца полтора не мог найти подходящий. Использую тот же, что и Вы. Вообще есть более удобный (как по мне) чем consolas. Описан последним под номером 1 здесь http://habrahabr.ru/post/120316/ - Inconsolata